# Does the size of Redux Store grow every time I change pages in my App?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

We're planning to use Redux with Redux-thunk in our React App. Typically, every time we open a page in our browser (from a menu or whatnot) we usually call some Action Creator from Redux. And let's say those action creators make a rest API call and finally fetch some data from a remote site, and store that info in our Redux store.

From the starting point, i.e. when I first load the app in my browser, every time I change a page the store will get larger. That means the memory print of my application grows as I change from the Employees Page to the Tasks Page, for example, etc.

What's the best practice in a typical Redux App? Is there a way to downsize the store as we move along the pages?

In the above example, I might not need the employee info anymore when I move to the Tasks Page but that info still takes memory space in my Redux Store. I'll probably need to re-fetch that Employee data if I move to the Employees Page again, anyway. So I feel like there is no point keeping that info in my store when I'm cruising within other pages of my app.

This is not a problem for many applications out there, but if we are working with large size data, or if we have too many pages in our app, then the memory problem really hits us.

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/garbage-collection-in-redux-applications

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you manage your state in your reducers. If you setup your reducer to replace the data in the store then no, the store will not grow larger.

```
function employeesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_EMPLOYEES:
      return {...state, employees: action.employees};
  }
  return state;
}
```

In another case, you can have a list in your reducer state and action that appends to the list indefinitely then yes, the store will grow larger.

```
function employeesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const newState = {...state};
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_EMPLOYEES:
      newState.employees.append(action.employees)
  }
  return newState;
}
```

You need a clear/reset mechanism in the above case.

This above is just a simple example but in a large application you can get "leaky" reducers where your dataset expands but that would be due to programming error or constantly appending data.

Another example where memory can constantly expand is if you implement a redux undo where you save your state each time so you can replay it. Here is a [library](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) that does that.